# Find if object in ArrayList has a specific field

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find out if an Object in ArrayList has a specific field with a specific value. I'd like to do it kinda like this, just with ArrayList instead of N individual objects:

```
SomeObject o1 = new SomeObject();
SomeObject o2 = new SomeObject();
...
SomeObject oN = new SomeObject();


boolean running = true;
while (running)
{
    //Do stuff
    running = o1.booleanField || o2.booleanField || ... || oN.booleanField;
}
```

I think it could be done with a for-each loop, but I'm not sure how. If what I said made any sense, please reply.

Comment: If you know the name of the field you can use reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a single-threaded scenario, you should:

- Parametrize the type of your `ArrayList` with the class of your objects, instead of using `Object`
- Don't use a `while` loop, but iterate the `ArrayList<YourObject>` with a `for` or enhanced `for` loop, and break when either element has the desired value for your `boolean` property, by invoking its getter
- This is not optimized to any measure, it will just keep iterating until it finds something or end the iteration if nothing is found

Some draft code within a main class here:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    // TODO populate with various foos
    for (Foo foo: foos) {
        if (foo.hasFoo()) {
            // TODO something
            break;
        }
    }
}
static class Foo {
    boolean foo;
    public Foo(boolean value) {
        foo = value;
    }
    public boolean hasFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reflection** is your answer .

Instead of **while loop** I prefer ***Iterator*** Interface ,
Iterate through the List and for each object try this :

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Object someObject = itr.next();
    for (Field field : someObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true); // You might want to set modifier to public first.
        Object value = field.get(someObject); 
        if (value != null) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GermannArlington , Can you please elaborate why there is no need ?

Comment: If somebody is asking such question than it is too early for them to dive into Reflection and most likely they are looking at accessible fields...

Answer (score 0):

When you say, `Object o1 = new Object();` you are not talking about `java.lang.Object`, right? Because the fields for `java.lang.Object` are defined in `javadoc` and you cannot ask for some kind of `booleanfield`, it won't exist.

If `ArrayList` contains several kind of objects, you can use `instanceof` or `.getClass()` to know the class object belongs to.

```
ArrayList<Object> objs = .... 
for (Object obj : objs) { 
     if (obj instanceof MyObject1) {
           MyObject1 myObject1 = (MyObject1) obj;
          // check for boolean field using its getter
     }
     else if (obj instanceof MyObject2) { 
           MyObject2 myObject2 = (MyObject2) obj;
          // check for boolean field using its getter
     }  
     ....
}
```

If `ArrayList` contains only one kind of objects, look at @Mena's answer.